# c#: how to check date falls between Dec to Jun?

Tags: c#

I need to check the condition that if today's day falls under 12/1 to 6/30 is true if not false.
7,8,9,10 and Nov not allowed

ex

```
int todayMonth = DateTime.Today.Month;

if(todayMonth < '12'|| todayMonth > '6') --- this doesn;t work
```

Comment: Think about the problem some more (once you get your compiler errors fixed). Month numbers reoccur every year. What you need to check is if today is between Dec 1 of this year and the end of the year or between Jan 1 of this year and Jun 30 of this year.

Comment: Keep in mind the Hebrew calendar has a 13th month as well.

Comment: `todayMonth` is an `int` so the comparison shouldn't be using a quoted value: `if(todayMonth < 12 || todayMonth > 6)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DateTime.Today.Month` has a return type of `int`, but you're checking against a `char` value type. This check also returns true everytime as every month value is less than 12 or greater than 6 months. Rewrite this to be:

```
int todayMonth = DateTime.Today.Month;

if(todayMonth >= 6 && todayMonth <= 12)
```

**Edit**: To check if the date is between 12/1 and 6/30, you can try the following (thanks to @RoyCohen):

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;

if (today.Month >= 12 || today.Month <= 6)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Pass");
}
```

Comment: That works if 7, 8, 9, 10, and 11 *are* allowed. The question says they're not, so it's about wrapping around the year.

Comment: @madreflection Good catch, will update answer.

Comment: 2>=6 and 2<=12 will fails

Comment: @James123: Yes, Hayden is addressing that based on my comment. Hang tight.

Comment: @James123 see update

Comment: couldn't you just do `month == 12 || month <= 6`?

Comment: @RoyCohen Updated based on your feedback.